# Importing Java packages and classes

Tags: java

I'm talking about the **stuff** we import.

Suppose, there is something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

`util` is the package and `Scanner` is the class, right?

**Can this be always generalised and be said that in the import statement, the first one would be java/javax (is there any other?), the second one package, the third class and the fourth, if any, will always be a method belonging to the class?**

Are there any exceptions, if so please name them.

Comment: no. you can say the last one is class, and the rest are package, if the last one is not `*`.

Comment: You should read [the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) about java packaging and importing said packages .

Answer (score 4):

> Can this be always generalised and be said that in the import statement, the first one would be java/javax (is there any other?), the second one package, the third class and the fourth, if any will always be a method belonging to the class?

Not really, no.

The package is `java.util`, and you'll *definitely* see other packages, including the ones you write.

Within a normal import statement, there'll be a package, then either a specific class name or a `*` (to import all the classes in a package). But the class name could be a nested class name, so you could have:

```
import foo.bar.Outer.Nested;
```

where `foo.bar` is the package name, and `Outer.Nested` is the class name.

Then there are static imports, where you import *members* of classes, e.g.

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
```

See the [Java tutorial on imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) for more details.

Comment: Can I also say that `Nested` a class inside another class `Outer`?

Comment: If we don't know the package being imported, can't we just tell which one is the package and which one's the class? I mean, where does the package end and where does the class begin, in my example, the last one `Scanner` was the class, but in yours, the last two are the class, i.e. `Outer` and `Nested`.

Comment: @KW123: Yes, a nested class is one declared within another class - but that's not the same as a package. You would usually tell the difference between a package and a class by naming convention - packages start with lower-case letters; classes start with upper-case letters.

Comment: Nice to see an answer from Jon on this question!

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not need to start with java, you can use anything as package name. Usually package names have a pattern like: `com.someone.project.any.package.Class` where `com.someone` represents the domain, `project` the project name and `any.package` your package hierarchy inside the project. This is just a convention but I would recommend you to use it.

Also take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

simple example from andEngine library:

```
org.andengine.entity.modifier.FadeOutModifier;
```

as you can see it has four nods. Last one is a class, extending modifier class, extending entity class, in package org.andengine... Also it does not start with java.

Hope it explains a bit

Answer (score 0):

In your example

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

`java.util` is the package, `Scanner` is the class you're importing from that package to be visible to the compiler.

See, for example, these lines from a the imports section of a pretty normal java file:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

These are all valid imports, which import the `Map` interface from `java.util` package, the `ImmutableMap` class from `com.google.common.collect` package, etc.